# Import Image from Dataverse Table into Excel with Office Script

Tags: excel, office-scripts, dataverse

I am trying to import a image from a data verse image attachment column. I am struggling with the Excel Script. This is what I have as of now:

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook, Image_2: string) {
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();

    // Insert picture picture_1
    let picture_1 = selectedSheet.addImage(Image_2);
    picture_1.setTop(372);
    picture_1.setLeft(372.75);
```

I am getting an error with script to save the script and wanted to find what I am doing wrong before I create the power automate flow.

Answer (score 0):

No sure how your code gets the Base64 string from Dataverse table. The code works well with Base64 string on sheet.

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    // get Base64 string from cell A1
    let Image_2 = selectedSheet.getCell(0,0).getText();
    let picture_1 = selectedSheet.addImage(Image_2);
    picture_1.setTop(20);
    picture_1.setLeft(20);
}
```

Base64 string

```
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
```

[image]

If Base64 string is from external resource, set `Image_2` as a parameter. You could assign the value (output of last step) to parameter `Image_2` when you set up running Office Script with PA.

Script: *SO-insert_image*

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook,
  Image_2: string) {
  let selectedSheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1") ;
  let picture_1 = selectedSheet.addImage(Image_2);
  picture_1.setTop(20);
  picture_1.setLeft(20);
}
```

[image]

---

***Note:*** `getActiveWorksheet` doesn't work when script is called by PA. It is equivalent to:

```
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getWorksheets()[0];
```

Suggest specify worksheet object with:

```
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getWorksheets()[2];
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet2");
```

Comment: I am getting this image from an external source. How do I assign a variable for the base64 data entry in the script?

Comment: It doesn't matter what's the external resource. You could assign it to parameter `Image_2` when you set up running Office Script with PA.